# Setting Up Continuous Integration for multiple project under one Azure Git Branch

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I have multiple project in a solution all under one branch. I've setup separate azure build pipeline for each ?
When I try to setup C I for each , the commits to one project triggers all build pipelines ?

The folder structure under the azure git repo branch is Root Folder --> Proj1 Folder 
Root Folder --> Proj2 Folder

Also the Checkout is at branch so it downloads all projects which I need to minimize to  project which gets the commits.[Azure Git Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH06x.jpg)

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the triggers for the pipeline. By default it will listen for all changes on that repository/branch. You need to edit the pipeline and add a path filter to the trigger.

1. Edit your pipeline and then click on the third tab "Triggers"
   [image: Triggers tab in Azure DevOps Pipeline]
2. Add a path filter 
   [image: Add path filter to the trigger in Azure DevOps]